# Problems with laravel between localhost and hosting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have the next problem, I have a project in Laravel 5.7 in my localhost computer and I upload this project to my Hosting on Bluehost, the problem is:
I have the file viewcustomers.blade.php in my localhost works ok without problems, but in my hosting this file Dont works...

This is the code:

```
@foreach($prendas as $prenda)
                            @if($clientes->id == $prenda->idcliente)
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><img src="../images/clientes/{{$clientes->nombre}} {{$clientes->apellido}}/{{$prenda->fotoprenda1}}" width="150"></td>
                                    <td align="center">{{$prenda->prenda}}</td>
                                    <td align="center">{{$prenda->marca}}</td>
                                    <td align="center">{{$prenda->modelo}}</td>
                                    <td align="center">{{$prenda->anio}}</td>
                                    <td align="center">$  {{$prenda->limitcredit}}</td>
                                    @if($prenda->status == "Sin Prestamos")
                                        <td bgcolor="green">Sin Prestamos</td>
                                        <td><a href="{{url('/addpawn/'.$prenda->idcliente."/".$prenda->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger">Agregar Prestamo</a></td>
                                    @elseif ($prenda->status == "En Empeño" and $prenda->restcredit < $prenda->limitcredit)
                                        <td bgcolor="red">Empeñada</td>
                                        <td><a href="{{url('/addmorepawn/'.$prenda->idcliente."/".$prenda->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger">Agregar Prestamo</a></td>
                                    @elseif ($prenda->status == "En Empeño" and $prenda->restcredit >= $prenda->limitcredit)
                                        <td bgcolor="red">Empeñada</td>
                                        <td>Sin Limite de Credito</td>
                                    @endif

                                </tr>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                        <tr>
                            <td>       </td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Prestamos Actuales</h3>
                    <hr>
                    <center>
                        @if($prenda->status == "Sin Prestamos" and $clientes->id == $prenda->idcliente)
                           <a href="{{url('/addpawn/'.$prenda->idcliente."/".$prenda->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger">Agregar Prestamo</a>
                        @elseif ($prenda->status == "En Empeño" and $prenda->restcredit < $prenda->limitcredit and $clientes->id == $prenda->idcliente)

                           <a href="{{url('/addmorepawn/'.$prenda->idcliente."/".$prenda->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger">Agregar Prestamo</a>

                        @elseif ($prenda->status == "En Empeño" and $prenda->restcredit >= $prenda->limitcredit and $clientes->id == $prenda->idcliente)
                            <h2 class="text-danger">Sin Limite de Credito</h2>
                        @endif
```

And this is the problem in the Hosting

> status == "Sin Prestamos" and $clientes->id ==
>   $prenda->idcliente): ?>
>                              idcliente."/".$prenda->id)); ?>" class="btn
>   btn-danger">Agregar Prestamo
>                           status == "En Empeño" and $prenda->restcredit limitcredit and $clientes->id ==
>   $prenda->idcliente): ?>
>
> ```
>                        <a href="<?php echo e(url('/addmorepawn/'.$prenda->idcliente."/".$prenda->id)); ?>"
> ```
>
> class="btn btn-danger">Agregar Prestamo
>
> ```
>                     <?php elseif($prenda->status == "En Empeño" and $prenda->restcredit >= $prenda->limitcredit and $clientes->id ==
> ```
>
> $prenda->idcliente): ?>
>                               Sin Limite de Credito
>                           
>              
>                       
>                           
>                               Fecha Prestamo
>                               Cantidad Prestada
>                               Plazo
>                               Interes
>                               Pago Quincenal
>                               Fecha Primer Pago
>                               Total a Pagar Prestamo
>                               Status
>                               Boleta de Empeño Arguments "Undefined variable: prenda (View:
>   /home/thealmfc/public_html/lonchedeadobada.xyz/resources/views/viewcustomers.blade.php)"

Any idea? thanks

Comment: Check your code, You closed `@foreach` wrongly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your code, you closed `@foreach` wrongly

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<h3 class="text-center">Prestamos Actuales</h3>
<hr>
<center>
    @if($prenda->status == "Sin Prestamos" and $clientes->id == $prenda->idcliente)
        <a href="{{url('/addpawn/'.$prenda->idcliente."/".$prenda->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger">Agregar Prestamo</a>
    @elseif ($prenda->status == "En Empeño" and $prenda->restcredit < $prenda->limitcredit and $clientes->id == $prenda->idcliente)

        <a href="{{url('/addmorepawn/'.$prenda->idcliente."/".$prenda->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger">Agregar Prestamo</a>

    @elseif ($prenda->status == "En Empeño" and $prenda->restcredit >= $prenda->limitcredit and $clientes->id == $prenda->idcliente)
        <h2 class="text-danger">Sin Limite de Credito</h2>
    @endif
```

Here variable `$prenda` is out of scope. You closed `@foreach` before this code snippet.

Comment: Please explain me more

Answer (score 0):

Your error level is diferent between your localhost and your hosting. 
Set

`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

on your localhost and you will see the same problem